# Update position whenever new item is added for sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code:

```
function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
  $(link).closest(".fields").hide("slow");
}

function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id)).prev().hide().show("slow");
    $("#sortable_shop").sortable({
      items: "li.sortable_shop_item",
      connectWith: "#sortable_shop",
      update: function() {
        $("li.sortable_shop_item input.sortable_shop_item_position").each(function(index) {
        $(this).val(index + 1);
      });
      }
    }).disableSelection();
}
```

I want it to update all `li.sortable_shop_item input.sortable_shop_item_position` whenever a new item is added/removed, so that all `li.sortable_shop_item input.sortable_shop_item_position` positions get updated at the same time. Currently, the `li.sortable_shop_item input.sortable_shop_item_position` is left blank whenever a new item is added/removed.

Note: The `$("#sortable_shop").sortable ...` that I am using in the add field is to make it sortable every time new item is added.

I have tried playing with `$(link).parent() ...` by adding `.sortable({ update: ...`, but it ain't working.

Please advise. Many thanks.